# Crash [RMMessageFormatter getFormatedStatusFromDisk] (IOS obj-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crashlytics

I have a crash in Crashlytics and i can't understand what it is. I found nothing on internet, it is really weird. 
The problem is unrecognized selector [RMMessageFormatter getFormatedStatusFromDisk]

I can't even find this class or this method in my workspace...

Here the crash stack :

```
    Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185e86530 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000196e640e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185e8d5f4 __methodDescriptionForSelector
    3  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185e8a3ac ___forwarding___ + 928
    4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185d8ec4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
    5  Dizzit                         0x00000001003624e0 -[RMMessageFormatter getFormatedStatusFromDisk] + 121500
    6  Dizzit                         0x0000000100361a3c -[RMMessageFormatter formatWithQueues:] + 118776
    7  Dizzit                         0x0000000100329478 -[RMMessageSender prepareMessage]
    8  Dizzit                         0x0000000100329838 -[RMMessageSender prepareAndSendMsg]
    9  Dizzit                         0x00000001003296e8 -[RMMessageSender flushSendingQueue]
    10 Dizzit                         0x000000010032a69c __24-[RMMessageSender flush]_block_invoke
    11 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001974b5994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    12 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001974b5954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    13 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001974c2780 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1848
    14 libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001974c3c4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
    15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019769522c _pthread_wqthread + 816
    16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000197694ef0 start_wqthread + 4
```

If someone can help me to understand what is RMMessage and how to fix this.

Best regards,

Comment: So what's your question? :)

Comment: hum i just would like to know what cause this crash, what is RMMessage...

Comment: So I suggest you modify your question to clarify what you want - do you also want a solution on how to fix it, or just information on the message?

Comment: Ok i have maybe found the problem. Google analytics send data every 20s (less or more). This is configured here :    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20
When i remove this line and do it manually i don't have this crash anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem.
Google analytics + AFNetworking seems to be the cause.
I had [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20 to send tracking data every 20s but sometimes i got this crash.

Don't remove this line, just set a negative value to stop automatic sent :
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = -1

I add [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch]; in applicationDidEnterBackground to  send tracking data when the user leave the app.

It seems ok now